# How to notify users about changes in the flutter application via MySQL database?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

The application that is to be developed is like social *platform* where we can post questions and get answers like **Stackoverflow** and Notification to the user application via User **Push Notifications** and to the app by system to notify about the updates and system settings.
The system shall notify users whenever they *vote, comment, reply or follow any
question* in the application developed in `flutter`.

Comment: What do you want to know exactly? What did you try already? What error did you get? Is the MySQL database local on the device or on a remote server? If it is local, how do you get new data in the database?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.